# How would I limit total outbound traffic?

Tags: ubuntu, network-traffic

I've had a look round and found solutions like `tc` to limit the total allowed bandwidth per user, but what I'm interested in is how to limit the total outbound traffic per user.

I have a server with DigitalOcean that has a 1TB bandwidth cap. Rather than limit the users bandwidth, I'd much rather prefer to set a static cap on the user and/or group. I'm using Ubuntu with a custom written panel. I have Apache and PHP set up to run as the defined user so that I can limit traffic, but I'm not sure as to how I would go about doing so.

Comment: I think you are confusing bandwidth (usually measured as the number of bits that can be sent in a second) with a data cap. These are two completely separate problems with different solutions.

Comment: @RonMaupin most likely. I want to create an outbound data cap per month per user -- if that makes sense